# in gql, how do i sort by a field in another class linked by referenceproperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

for example, 2 classes in a 1-to-many relationship:

```
class owner(db.model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class cat(db.model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    owner = db.ReferenceProperty(owner)
```

so how do i produce a list of cats ordered by owner.name (then optionally by cat.name)?

i tried
    "SELECT * FROM cat ORDER BY owner.name"
but got
    Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol .name

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't; this would require a join, which the datastore doesn't support.  If you need to sort like this, denormalize your data and include the owner name in the cat model.